# Print cross using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, button, textarea, logic

I have this code on my external javascript

```
function cross()
{
    var output2 = document.getElementById('output2');
    var a = "*"
      , b = " "
      , i = 0
      , j = 0
      , k = 0
    ;
    for(i = 1, k = input; i <= input; i++, k--)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= input; j++)
        {
            if (j == i || j == k)
            {
                output2.value += a;
            }
            else
            {
                output2.value += b;
            }
            output2.value += '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

and this html button on my 1st page + text area on my 2nd page so the text area will show in second page (`halaman.html`) after I click the button on 1st page.

```
<!-- code page 1-->    
<a href="halaman.html"><input type="button" value="Muncul page baru" onclick="cross();"></a><br />
<!-- code page 2-->
<textarea id="output2" rows="20" cols="90"></textarea>
```

The cross doesn't show on the 2nd page. What's wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript can not set the value of an element on a page that is not even created yet.

You can submit a form with the value, but you would have to use a GET request since JavaScript will not be able to access the POST data without some help a serverside language.

Other options is to use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage). Set it on the first page, read it on the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible to do. Because when you navigate to second page, there is no javascript available from previous page.
 You need to store your result in server state or pass the result through the querystring

Answer (score 0):

The javascript only works on the first page. You could send a GET variable through the URL and check for that variable on the second page.

You could also put page2 on a iframe.